# Information Ratio Confusion in Grinold's Signal Weighting Paper

Tags: portfolio-optimization, modern-portfolio-theory, asset-allocation

In the procedure Grinold outlines in his 2010 paper "[Signal Weighting](https://baixardoc.com/preview/signal-weighting-by-richard-grinold-5cc218ca43c93)" for optimally combinining $J$ raw alphas, $\mathbf{a}_j$, he first assumes each $\mathbf{a}_j$ has been scaled so its information ratio (IR) is $1$, i.e., $\mathbf{a}_j' \mathbf{V}^{-1}\mathbf{a}_j = 1$.

He then associates a "source" portfolio with each $\mathbf{a}_j$, defined by $\mathbf{q}_j= \mathbf{V}^{-1} \mathbf{a}_j$. Since $\mathbf{a}_j' \mathbf{V}^{-1}\mathbf{a}_j = 1$, it seems to me that the IR of each $\mathbf{q}_j$ is $\frac{\mathbf{a}_j^{'} 
 \mathbf{V}^{-1} \mathbf{a}_j}{\sqrt{\mathbf{a}_j^{'} \mathbf{V}^{-1}\mathbf{a}_j}} = 1$.

I don't think this can be the case though since, later in the paper, he refers to a $J$ element vector containing the IRs for each source portfolio, which he uses throughout the remainder of the paper, and I don't see why he'd do this if they were all $1$?

E.g., he later defines the optimally combined portfolio as a linear combination of the source portfolios $\mathbf{q} = \sum_{j} \mathbf{q}_{j} \omega_{j}$ and states that its expected return is given by  $\sum_{j} \text{IR}_j \cdot \omega_{j}$.

Can somebody please shed some light on this for me. Are the IRs of the source portfolios $1$? If so, what's the use for the vector of IRs he defines?

Thanks